# "A heap has been corrupted" error when running Database Tuning Analyser?

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-tuning-advisor

I am running SQL database tuning analyser to investigate an issue with particular SQL queries running extremely slowly and at ~20% I consistently get the following error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x777daa3c in dtaengine.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted.

I am using a SQL profile trace file as my workload, connected to the database that was originally profiled to generate it and have selected the option to generate online recommendations where possible in addition to the following;

- Employ no partitioning strategy
- Keep all existing physical design structures

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue?